# Check if text covers cell

Tags: itext7

I need to know how to check if a text inside a cell is covering it. If not, I want to cover the rest of the space with dots.

For instance, say I have this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Total:").SetFont(FontRegular).SetFontSize(FontSize);
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.Add(p);
```

And I say the cell occupies the whole table, or half, or whatever. Getting the width of the cell is easy. I just get the current column's width through the table (I don't understand why the GetWidth of the cell or paragraph method returns null...).
But how do can I get the width occupied by the paragraph? I need to know that to add as many dots as needed, for formatting purposes.

As this will come through some string I can't really afford to set it manually each time. I have to have it be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getting cell width is easy, you can use tab stops to fill the rest of the line with dots. Here is an example of a helper method:

```
private Cell createCell(String content, float cellWidth) {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    if (content != null) {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(content);
        p.addTabStops(new TabStop(cellWidth, TabAlignment.RIGHT, new DottedLine()));
        p.add(new Tab());
        cell.add(p);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

It will add the tabstop and necessary tab to fill the rest of the last line with dots.

So if I use this method e.g. in the following way:

```
Table table = new Table(new float[]{150, 50})
        .addCell(createCell("cell 1, 1", 150))
        .addCell(createCell("cell 1, 2", 50))
        .addCell(createCell("cell 2, 1", 150))
        .addCell(createCell("cell 2, 2", 50))
        .addCell(createCell("cell 3, 1", 150))
        .addCell(createCell(null, 50));
doc.add(table);
```

The result would look similar to the following:

[image: Tab stops for filling last line with dots]

Of course, you can decide whether to fill empty cells with dots, maybe move the tab stop position a bit to the left etc, but this should give you an idea of an approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks. That's just what I needed. I had managed to find a workaround, but with this built-in option it´s way better and easier. :)